# Object reference not set to an instance of an object On singleton class

Tags: c#, exception, singleton

I have a class named `DAL` with the methods to connect to my `database`.
When I create a new project, I always go on `Add Existing Item` and Add this class. Always worked ! But now that I imported to my new project, I got that error on the title... I hope some of you guys could explain to me.
I Know that this exception happens when the method returns a NULL value.(Maybe not).

Here is my code:

```
#region Singleton
  public sealed class Singleton
    {
       static readonly DAL instance = new DAL(); //HERE IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION OCCURS

       // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
       // not to mark type as beforefieldinit

  public static DAL Instance
    {
       get
          {
             return instance;
          }
     }
}
#endregion
```

And here is where I call this class.

```
namespace BD
{
    public class BDAssociado
    {
        private DAL _dal;
        public BDAssociado()
        {
            _dal = DAL.Singleton.Instance;

        }
     }
}
```

Dal Constructor:

```
public DAL()
  {
   _Conexao = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameOfConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
  }
```

Comment: it might be that constructor of DAL is throwing the exception. Debug it or post the stack trace

Comment: The exception occurs on that line I commented: `static readonly DAL instance = new DAL();`  But what is stranger, is that, this same class is working fine on my others project... ;\

Comment: The only way an exception could occur in that line is that the constructor of DAL throws it. You need to check where in DAL the exception originates.

Comment: Can you post the constructor code in the DAL class?

Comment: And just a silly thing but can you check whether this connectionstring key exist in your config file?

Comment: @AzharKhorasany Yes it does... As I said, It's very strange, because on the others project, this class works perfect... ;\

Comment: What do you mean when you say "when I imported to my new project"?? in the description above?

Comment: @AzharKhorasany Ok, now it's working -.-" I have no idea HOW/WHY... oO  
I typed the wrong `ConnectionStringName` on the constructor on purpose and fired the same exception... I guess it was really wrong before oO don't know...

Comment: @AzharKhorasany Import: I created my project, Added a Library Class then I Right Clicked on my Project `Add -> Add Existing Item ` and searched on my other project's folder and selected this class(`DAL`). you know ?

Comment: So what I said earlier was correct :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your connection string key exist in the config file.

Answer (score 2):

Check if it is `null` before returning:

```
public static DAL Instance
    {
        get
          {
             if (instance == null) 
             {
                 instance = new DAL();
             }
             return instance;
          }
     }
```

Comment: I used to use this method you just posted... But I read it wasn't the saffest one. So I changed for that one... The way you posted, it works fine. But as the way I posted it's working on the others projects, I'd like to know why it is not working now... You know ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro - because when you retrieve the `DAL Instance` the getter returns `instance` - if it has not been initialized then you get the object reference exception.  What I have provided checks before returning, so it is safer.